# Zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to create a `0 or 1` to `0 or 1` relationship in a database?

For example, let's say I have a table of managers and a table of artists. A manager can only manage one artist, and an artist can only have one manager. 
However, a manager can be without an artist (i.e. looking for an artist to manage) and an artist might not have a manager.

Is there any way to do this? Creating a foreign key in either table would just create a `1 to many` relationship.

Answer (score 12):

This is fairly simple.

You have a 1:1 relationship which may not exist.

So you have a `unique` `foreign key` which is `nullable` and therefore can be specified to point at nothing.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE manager (
    id int primary key,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE artist (
     id int primary key,
     manager_id int unique references manager(id)
     ...
);
```

Now the artist cannot have more than one manager, and the manager cannot have more than one artist.  And the artist may not have a manager.

Comment: In most RDBMS, this would only allow you to create only one unmanaged artist. The `unique` constraint would not allow a second `NULL`.

Comment: @Bret: The SQL standard specification does state that the `UNIQUE` constraint must ignore `NULL` values when checking for uniqueness. Most RDBMS implement it correctly: Oracle / PostgreSQL / MySQL / MariaDB. SQL server does not, but it's possible to get the same behavior by adding a `WHERE column IS NOT NULL` clause on the constraint.

Comment: Because the 0-1 is symmetric I think that we will had the same behavior if the FK was in the other side (artist_id on the manager table). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As I think, there should be `separate table` to manage relation. It will contain both table's keys, but there will be a constraint to prevent duplicate composite key.

In this way, you need not to insert keys for Managers who don't have Artist, or Artists who do not have any Manager (Avoids Null entries)

Comment: I believe you would need two unique constraints, one on each of the two fields in the relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a foreign key field on the manager table pointing to the artist they are managing, allowing nulls.

You can then use it to find which artist they are managing and find the manager for a particular artist.

Answer (score 0):

In RDBMS you can get three kind of relations between tables

> One to one; 
>   one to many; 
>   many to many

There is nothing like one to zero relation but you may get one to zero relationship while working i.e some data may exists where 1-0 relationship happens but you can't explicitly define 1-0 relationship like one-one,one to many or many to many relationship.

Comment: You even can not define this relation like `One to One` or `One to Many`. They are actually concepts and there are different ways to workout on them.

Comment: Well Yes I meant that too (Y)