# I need to create tables with "one to zero or to one" relationships in sqlite. This is what I have so far, is it right?

Tags: sqlite

So I have this so far, I have to bind these two tables (one-to-zero or to-one relationship)

```
DROP TABLE if exists Person;
CREATE TABLE Person(
       ID int NOT NULL,
       Name varchar (40),
       PRIMARY KEY(ID)); 


DROP TABLE if exists Pass;
CREATE TABLE Pass(
       ID int REFERENCES Person,
       Owner int,
       PRIMARY KEY(ID),
       FOREIGN KEY(Owner) REFERENCES Person(ID));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341150/zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship)

Comment: @milena: Are you sure you need the "REFERENCES Person" in the ID int definition?

Comment: I don't know, do you think I should delete and it would be okay?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a different child table definition, because the
`Pass` table in your question doesn't make any sense; it doesn't
contain any information of its own.

```
    CREATE TABLE Person (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        Dept INT REFERENCES Department(DeptID);
    );

    CREATE TABLE Department (
        DeptID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
    );
```

The `Dept` column of the `Person` table has a 1 : 0 or 1 relationship
to the `Department` table, because each row in the `Person` table
(1) can contain either zero or one (0 or 1) references to a row in
the `Department` table (the `Dept` column can be NULL).

Meaning that a person can be assigned to a department or not, but if
they are, they can only be assigned to 1 department.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! I try to use it for my exam on Tuesday!